# qplot facet two histograms

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

Hi I have the following columns in a table:

```
Person
Score1
Score2
```

and I can plot a historgram of the scores using qplot:

```
qplot(Score1,data = dat,geom="histogram")
```

which is fine, - but how do I plot two histograms side by side - one with Score1 and one with Score2.

I have also managed to plot both on the same graph using ggplot and melting Score1 and Score2:

```
m <- melt(dat[,c(2,3)])

>head(m)

    variable      value
  1 Score1        50
  2 Score2        70
  3 Score1        45
  4 Score2        30.5
  5 Score1        70
  6 Score2        40

ggplot(m,aes(value)) + geom_bar(binwidth = 1)
```

however when trying to use facet_wrap()

```
ggplot(m,aes(value)) + geom_bar(binwidth = 1) + facet_wrap(variable ~ Score_type)
```

I get:

```
Error in layout_base(data,cols,drop = drop)
At least one layer must contain all variables used for facetting
```

Any ideas? I will post if I solve this myself.Also is it possible to order the x axis by Score1 or Score2?

Thanks!

Comment: i'd rather not have them on the same graph. looks messy!

Comment: Then take a look at the second linked question.

Comment: Pretty sure @nograpes is right. Even w/o data and no pointer to what the poster wanted, it seems the answer lies in the second linked question.

Comment: @nograpes - hi thanks, just one thing with the second question is that the variable they are plotting there is in one column. i have two separate columns so the melt function used in a few solutions to that question won't work for me.

Comment: @brucezepplin The `melt` function will make your two columns into one column, making it easy to plot your histograms side-by-side with `ggplot`.

Comment: @brucezepplin But there are other problems with your question that make it difficult to answer. You should read the posting guide, include a reproducible example. and make sure that your question hasn't been answered before.

Comment: @nograpes - yes have almost got there with the solutions on the second thread posted. I'll amend my question.

Answer (score 0):

Got it- minor error in the facet_wrap function parameter I passed. It works with:

```
ggplot(m,aes(value)) + geom_bar(binwidth = 1) + facet_wrap(~variable)
```